# 12.04 too slow (Asus 1215b)

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus 1215B (on formatted hdd) and it seems to work even more slowly than win7. Htop says that system load is low and after some updates compiz now won't eating 50% CPU time. Even in 2d system is slow -why? (ATI drivers don't installed - because ubuntu is starting to die under them)

Comment: You may need to be more descriptive about what actions in particular are slow, and your hardware and your setup.

Comment: try live session using a live cd, if it runs fine, try to res-install ubuntu once again (it will take about 15 mins or less) then  test ubuntu, install ccsm and check the stability. (ubuntu 12.04 is very slow on some old asus PCs that are low on ram, I got a asus p5pe-vm MB with 1GB ram and 128 nVidia VGA and ubuntu 12.04 runs great but it is not faster than my 10.10 system!)

Comment: Dash opening at least 2 sec, software center opening >10 sec, any other prog starting from 5 to 10 sec, unity periodicaly crashing etc. Config: AMD Brazos E450 1600MHz, 8gb ram, video hybrid(using pc ram), 500gb WD(SMART green). HDD 40gb /, 8gb swap, 420gb /home.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a fresh install and then install open source AMD drivers, plus if you are low on ram, try to use lower RAM consuming DE like LXDE, or even wmii if learning curve is not steep for you.In addition close unnecessary services running and even check the startup application. I think that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. First, update your Ubuntu system. Then use Cairo Dock or some other light element in place of Unity 2D or 3D. It might help.

Comment: It would help if you provided details about how to do these things, especially about how to replace Unity with Cairo.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same model and everything works perfectly including suspend. I installed amd rivers via command line as jockey gives errors.

Comment: Please expand your answer giving a step by step guide where to download the drivers and how to install.  At the moment your answer doesnt really help  the OP.